# To build a multi-dimensional json array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, multidimensional-array

I want a multi-dimensional array in a specific json format from the table that is returned through an sql query. The table looks like this: (excuse the raw format)

|     Date    |     Count         | Name     |

| 2013-12-19  |               252 | Value 1  |

| 2013-12-19  |                60 | Value 2  |

| 2013-12-19  |                 8 | Value 3  |

| 2013-12-26  |               173 | Value 1  |

| 2013-12-26  |                32 | Value 2  |

| 2013-12-26  |                 6 | Value 3  |

I want a multi-dimensional json array in the below mentioned format:

{2013-12-19: [{Name:"Value 1",Count:"252"},{Name:"Value 2",Count:"60"},{Name:"Value 3",Count:"8"}],

2013-12-26: [{Name:"Value 1",Count:"173"},{Name:"Value 2",Count:"32"},{Name:"Value 3",Count:"6"}]
}

I tried a code but I'm facing trouble in adding all the date values inside that array.
Here is the sample code that I tried:

```
    $query2_result = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows_query2 = mysql_num_rows($query2_result);
    $records = array();

    if($rows_query2 > 0) {
     while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query2_result)) {
        if(!array_key_exists($r[date][name],$records[$r[date]])) {
                    $records[$r[date]][name] = array();

        }

         $records[$r[date]]["count"] = $r[count];
         $records[$r[date]]["name"] = $r[name];
      }
    }
    echo json_encode($records);
```

I'm getting only one array for each date mentioned. Like this:

{"2013-12-19":{"name":"Value 1","count":"775"},"2013-12-26":{"name":"Value 1","count":"397"}}

Kindle help me out. Thanks in davance.

Comment: Think about using mysqli rather than mysql which is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $records = array();

 if($rows_query2 > 0) {
 while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query2_result)) {
      $records[$r['date']][] = array('name'=>$r['name'],'count'=>$r['count']);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do to add all records for a given date to sub-array is this:

```
$records[$r[date]][] = $r;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change while logic with below one

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query2_result)) {
    $records[$r["date"]][]  = array(  "Name" => $r["name"], "Count" => $r["count"]);
}
```